# Newbie question: Java class has a member variable that is an interface type. Can someone clarify?

Tags: java, interface

Could someone point me in the right direction. I am learning about the Strategy Pattern ([on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)) and in the code sample, there is something that I do not understand.

The line with `public IBillingStrategy Strategy` what is this?

```
class Customer {
    // Get/Set Strategy
    public IBillingStrategy Strategy { get; set; }  // <---- This confuses me

    public Customer(IBillingStrategy strategy) {
        this.drinks = new List<double>();
        this.Strategy = strategy;
    }
 // code that I omitted
}

interface IBillingStrategy {
    double GetActPrice(double rawPrice);
}
```

I know you cannot instantiate instances of interfaces. And I know classes are suppose to implement interfaces with a keyword. Idk what that is called and I failed in my google search attempts.

Comment: Yes you are right but if you see closely the implementation is   below   static BillingStrategy normalStrategy() {
        return rawPrice -> rawPrice;
    }
  
    // Strategy for Happy hour (50% discount)
    static BillingStrategy happyHourStrategy() {
        return rawPrice -> rawPrice / 2;
    }

Comment: Please update the code with java version, you current code in C#.

Comment: my bad on the C# thing. Unfortunately I cant change the title :(

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing out the static keywords, that helps!

Comment: Hey @Crunkmastaflexx , Can you please accept the answer and close this topic. Thanks :-)

Comment: @spandey I have a follow up newbie question. What is happening at:
BillingStrategy normalStrategy() { return rawPrice -> rawPrice; }
what is happening with "rawPrice"? Shouldn't normalStrategy take in rawPrice as a parameter?

Comment: yes thats correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, this isn't Java. You can't write getter setter methods like this in Java: (This is C#)

```
public IBillingStrategy Strategy { get; set; }
```

Secondly, if you scroll down, you will see implementations of this interface:

```
class NormalStrategy : IBillingStrategy
{
    public double GetActPrice(double rawPrice) => rawPrice;
}

class HappyHourStrategy : IBillingStrategy
{
    public double GetActPrice(double rawPrice) => rawPrice * 0.5;
}
```

So this is basically **code-to-interface pattern**. Which basically means, you are designing your *Customer* class in such a way that an instance of Customer can hold either NormalStrategy or HappyHourStrategy as it's instance variable.

Thus if you see the main method:

```
var firstCustomer = new Customer(normalStrategy);
```

First customer is a customer having NormalStrategy (not a happy hour one).

Whereas, second customer is a customer having HappyHourStrategy.

```
Customer secondCustomer = new Customer(happyHourStrategy);
```

So coming to your doubt:
**I know you cannot instantiate instances of interfaces.**

You are absolutely right. So how is this working?
Answer is that : the implementation is injected into your code through the constructor or a method call.

Here it is being injected through constructor.

```
var normalStrategy    = new NormalStrategy();
var firstCustomer = new Customer(normalStrategy);
```

So, your code knows about the interface or abstract class and can call anything that is defined on this contract.

This is a subset of the Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP), the L of the SOLID principles.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really helps! I also look forward to learning about SOLID and code-to-injection